# Shortcut to call multiple userform option buttons?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, radio-button

I have a userform with 25 OptionButton (OptionButton1, OptionButton2, etc..)

As it is, to have each of these options called, I created private subs OptionButton1_Click, OptionButton2_Click, etc..

Is there any way to access the different options without creating 25 different subs? (i.e. OptionButton[x]_Click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is no, but have a look [here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/) for an interesting work-around. You could essentially fake a control array.

Besides what is mentioned in the post, you may additionally want to consider storing some kind of Tag in the OptionButton.Tag so that when it is clicked you can (if you wish) know which OptionButton was clicked.

Comment: Yea, I don't think it's possible, but this is a good work-around. I decided it to be best to make the 25 private subs, set my variable and call another sub with the code.  But I'll keep this in mind for the future. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Actually, I think making 25 methods that call a central method is the wisest choice--it's what I would have done it. Clarity is (almost) always more important than code length.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the option buttons. For example:

```
for i = 1 to 25

    If Controls("OptionButton" & i).Value = True Then

       'perform operation if OptionButton is clicked

     End If

Next i
```

Comment: If each option button has a different name, how can I activate this loop without 25 different OptionButton[i]_Click subs?

Comment: If they are not in the format OptionButton1, OptionButton2, Optionbutton3, etc... then the code I wrote won't work. My recommendation would be to change all of your option button names to OptionButton1, OptionButton2, etc...

Comment: They are named like that. I'm just not sure how that For Loop is going to be activated. Where do I put that code? if I put it under the Userform Initialize sub, it will run at the beginning once and nothing will happen because none of those option buttons will have been clicked yet.  That would require a command button I think, and I would prefer not using that.